# PowerShell - What is the difference between the `begin` block and anything outside?

Tags: powershell

If I write a function like this:

```bsh
function a {
    begin {
        do-something
    }
}
```

doesn't it do the same thing as this one?

```bsh
function a {
    do-something
}
```

What difference does the `begin` make?

Comment: See [About Functions Advanced Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7#begin)

Comment: Yes. But the `begin` block runs once, and anything outside `begin process end` also runs once.

Comment: Wehere is the difference?

Comment: `Begin` blocks, as well as `Process` blocks are needed when you are dealing with arrays and pipelines. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61943909/2150063) below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See is these provide any edification:

> [About Language Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7)
>
> [Piping Objects to Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7)
>
> You can control how a function processes input from the pipeline using
>   Begin, Process, and End keywords.
>
> [Windows PowerShell Cookbook, 3rd Edition by Lee Holmes](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-powershell-cookbook/9781449359195/ch04.html?afsrc=1)

Like pipeline-oriented functions, the Foreach-Object cmdlet lets you define commands to execute before the looping begins, during the looping, and after the looping completes:

```
"a","b","c" | Foreach-Object `
-Begin { "Starting"; $counter = 0 } `
-Process { "Processing $_"; $counter++ } `
-End { "Finishing: $counter" }

Starting
Processing a
Processing b
Processing c
Finishing: 3
```

> [Understanding PowerShell Begin, Process, and End blocks](https://4sysops.com/archives/understanding-powershell-begin-process-and-end-blocks/)
>
> [Advanced PowerShell Functions: Begin to Process to End](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2019/05/13/advanced-powershell-functions-begin-to-process-to-end/)

One more thing:

> as per Don Jones a PowerShell mvp, he says, then PROCESS block is only
>   used when the command is run using pipeline input. In that case,
>   objects are bound to input parameters one at a time, and PROCESS is
>   executed. If you just run the script straight, meaning with no
>   pipeline input, then PROCESS is ignored.

So, if we look at the defined goals of the implementation specifics, we have:

> Begin
>
> ***This block is used to provide optional one-time pre-processing
>   for the function.*** The PowerShell runtime uses the code in this block
>   one time for each instance of the function in the pipeline.
>
> Process
>
> ***This block is used to provide record-by-record processing for
>   the function.*** This block might be used any number of times, or not at
>   all, depending on the input to the function. For example, if the
>   function is the first command in the pipeline, the Process block will
>   be used one time. If the function is not the first command in the
>   pipeline, the Process block is used one time for every input that the
>   function receives from the pipeline. If there is no pipeline input,
>   the Process block is not used.
>
> A Filter is a shorthand representation of a function whose body is
>   composed entirely of a process block.
>
> ***This block must be defined if a function parameter is set to accept
>   pipeline input.*** If this block is not defined and the parameter accepts
>   input from the pipeline, the function will miss the values that are
>   passed to the function through the pipeline.
>
> Also, if the function/cmdlet supports confirmation requests (the
>   -SupportsShouldProcess parameter is set to $True), the call to the ShouldProcess method must be made from within the Process block.
>
> End
>
> This block is used to ***provide optional one-time post-processing***
>   for the function.

Comment: Yes, but if I provide the contents of the `begin` block outside of it, the result is the same.

Comment: The doc says anything outside begin-process-end is ignored if they're present. Interesting.

Comment: Yeppers, and if you do a full function in the editor and write any code after the END statement, the editor will show it as a syntax error and any run of it will fail. Well, it always did for me.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @iRon and @postanote comments, the `Begin` block in a function only applies when you are developing ['Advanced Functions'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods) a.k.a. functions that are designed for ***pipelining***.

Also, `Begin` blocks and `Process` blocks don't really come into play unless you start dealing with **arrays** or lists of objects. Dealing with many objects require you to write code that properly knows how to handle the stream of objects.

Most functions are simple `input -> process -> output` for example let's do a simple hello program:

```
Function Write-Greeting {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
            $name
    )
    Write-Host "Hello: $name"
}

PS C:\> Write-Greeting "schuelermine"
Hello: schuelermine
```

But what happens if you want to doing something more, say, we want to say hello to multiple people:

```
$LotsOfPeople = @("HAL9256", "schuelermine", "Jon Skeet")

PS C:\> Write-Greeting $LotsOfPeople
Hello: HAL9256 schuelermine Jon Skeet
```

Well that's not exactly what we want. I want to iterate through them all, and introduce everyone once at a time. To do this we would now have to do this with a loop:

```
Function Write-Greeting {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
            $name
    )
    $name | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Hello: $_"
    }
}

PS C:\> Write-Greeting $LotsOfPeople    
Hello: HAL9256
Hello: schuelermine
Hello: Jon Skeet
```

That's better. But it required a bunch of extra code. Now, I hear this amazing pipeline capability from PowerShell, let's try it:

```
PS C:\> "schuelermine" | Write-Greeting 
Hello: schuelermine
```

Yay! We are using pipelines. We also hear that the benefit of pipelines is that it will take an array of strings and pass each string one string at a time down the pipeline. We have an array of people, we have a function, so now let's pipe lots of people to it:

```
PS C:\> $LotsOfPeople | Write-Greeting
Hello: Jon Skeet
```

Well, that's not what we expected.

The reason that it's not working as expected is that we haven't written our function to handle a stream of pipeline input.

The `$LotsOfPeople` array of strings were indeed passed down the pipeline, one at a time, but our function is written to only handle one object. PowerShell decides that because the function isn't written to handle streams of objects from the pipeline, it ends up that the last object in the pipeline, is the object that is passed to the function.

***This is why `Begin` and `Process` blocks are different than straight code, they tell PowerShell that this function is written to handle streams of objects properly.***

Ok. Great! So what happens if we just add a `Begin` block, that should magically make it pipeline aware, right?

```
Function Write-Greeting {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
            $name
    )
    Begin {
        Write-Host "Hello: $name"
    }
}

PS C:\> $LotsOfPeople | Write-Greeting
Hello:
```

Well that's unexpected. I got nothing. But I thought I just made it pipeline aware?

The reason is that the `Begin` block is the code that is executed ***before*** pipeline input is passed to it. Since we have no input passed to it yet, we get no greeting.

This is where we ***actually*** need to use a `Process` block. `Process` blocks tell PowerShell what code to "Process" with the input one item at a time.

```
Function Write-Greeting {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
            $name
    )
    Process {
        Write-Host "Hello: $name"
    }
}

PS C:\> $LotsOfPeople | Write-Greeting
Hello: HAL9256
Hello: schuelermine
Hello: Jon Skeet
```

By simply adding the `Process` block, and using pipelining, we eliminate the need for the `ForEach-Object` loop. ***The `Process` block *becomes* the `ForEach-Object` loop in the function.***

Similarly, `Begin` blocks are for code that we need to do *before* we loop through our objects. e.g. if we need to initialize a counter, open a persistent connection, or introduce the class name that we only want to do once:

```
Function Write-Greeting {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
            $name
    )
    Begin {
        Write-Host "Welcome to PowerShell 101 Class"
    }
    Process {
        Write-Host "Hello: $name"
    }
}

PS C:\> $LotsOfPeople | Write-Greeting
Welcome to PowerShell 101 Class
Hello: HAL9256
Hello: schuelermine
Hello: Jon Skeet
```

Similarly, we can use the `End` Block to do things at the end of the `Process` loop. e.g. closing connections, or in this case counting how many computers we will need for the class.

```
Function Write-Greeting {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
            $name
    )
    Begin {
        Write-Host "Welcome to PowerShell 101 Class"
        $ClassAttendance = 0
    }
    Process {
        Write-Host "Hello: $name"
        $ClassAttendance += 1
    }
    End {
        Write-Host "We will need $ClassAttendance computers"
    }
}

PS C:\> $LotsOfPeople | Write-Greeting
Welcome to PowerShell 101 Class
Hello: HAL9256
Hello: schuelermine
Hello: Jon Skeet
We will need 3 computers
```